# Software to use a spare monitor as a personal dashboard with custom data feeds?

Tags: software-rec, python, libraries, dashboard, data-visualization

I'm looking for anything that would allow me to use my third monitor for some neat data visualization. Ideally this would be running full screen, with focus on really nice aesthetics.

I'm planning to feed it all kinds of data to chart/display, such as a real time visitor count on my websites, my reddit karma count over time, and whatever else comes to my mind. I'd prefer to use Python to feed this data to the software, but I'm open to anything, really.

If there's no such thing, I'd gladly hear any suggestions on what Python libraries y'all would recommend for implementing such a thing.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @Rico yes, see accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dashing available at http://shopify.github.io/dashing/

It's Sinatra based framework that lets you build beautiful dashboards. Drag & Drop interface for re-arranging your widgets, ...
In Ruby and open source.

[image: Dashing]

**OR**

Dashku available at https://github.com/itadakimasu/dashku

For creating dashboards and widgets in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript and it's also open source.

[image: Dashku]

Comment: The both seem pretty heavyweight to me? The first needs Ruby and Sinatra - and a web server? The second needs Node, MongoDB **and** Redis! Depending on the need, I'd think it much easier to simply code up some web pages and serve from Node or Python. But both of these are interesting products, thanks for sharing.

Comment: Dashing appears to be a dead project and is no longer maintained. Not advised for new work.

Answer (score -1):

#### UPDATE 2017-12-09:

The anonymous downvoter brought me back to this old answer. These days I use Node-RED to do quick Dashboards without needing much (if any) coding.

---

#### ORIGINAL ANSWER

I would simply fire up a browser window, move it to the monitor and do F11 to hide the UI parts.

I would personally use Node.JS to provide a simple web service to display my dashboards & I've done similar things both for work and personal use. Node is good because you only need a single language for both the server and the client end processing. JavaScript libraries such as Angular.JS make creating dashboards a pretty simple task. The last one I did was for an Arduino-based home monitor and was served from a Raspberry Pi.

Of course, if Python is your thing, it is also easy to create a simple web service. There are plenty of examples for Python as there are for Node.JS.

If you find it a pain to re-set up the monitor display each time you reboot, then something like AutoHotKey could be used to automate it.

Comment: Seriously! Downvote after nearly 4 years! And with no comment as to why? Really not at all helpful to anyone. Anyway, this prompted me to update the answer.